# Using LINQ to get one entity with the most of a child entity

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have an entity in Entity Framework 4 called `Topic`. `Topic` has a navigation property to a collection of `Reply` entities.

I am trying to craft a query that obtains the most popular topic based on the number of replies.

```
entityContainer.Topics.Single(x => x./* has the most replies of any topic */);
```

I'm not sure how to craft a query to accomplish this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might accomplish what you're looking to do.

```
var mostPopularTopic = entityContainer.Topics
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Replies.Count())
    .FirstOrDefault();

if(mostPopularTopic != null) // If there were any topics...
{
    // ...
}
```

I imagine this is going to have terrible perf, tho.

A better option might be to denormalize your data (slightly) and add a reply count column to the `Topic` table.  Then you can index that column, and do a simple sort and retrieve for row.  This will avoid a whole table scan of `Topics` and a count (at query time) on every `Replies` entry.

The trade-off will be that you have to be careful to ensure that the `Replies` count always gets updated, or live with results that aren't always completely up to date and do a background job to rebuild these values.

Comment: `OrderByDescending` (just deleted my answer, 10 sec too slow :))

Comment: Apologies if I'm incorrect and overstating the perf problem.  But I still think you'll have a full table scan because the DB can't really index on count on its own.

Comment: Ah, my first comment was only related to the code snippet. I had written it before you added the notes about performance :) Agree with the performance warning...